# Call to a member function find() on a non-object error in unix only

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.0 and Wamp and it's all good. However, production server is unix Ubuntu. Both computers access the same mysql data. 
I have these relations:

```
Model setup.php
var $belongsTo = array('Client', 'User');

Model client.php
var $hasMany = array('Setup');

Model user.php
var $hasMany = array('Setup');
```

Everything works great in localhost WAMP, but the production server is unix ubunto, to which I copy the whole directory. After chmod 777 everything, the app works fine except these errors:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: Client [APP/View/Setups/index.ctp, line 38]

```
index.php line 38
<td><?php echo $this->Html->link($setup['Client']['name'], array('controller' =>
'clients', 'action' => 'view', $setup['Setup']['client_id'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

> Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/View/Setups/view.ctp, line 66]

```
view.php    line 66
<?php echo $this->Html->link($setup['User']['name'], array('controller' => 'users',
'action' => 'view', $setup['User']['id'])); ?>`
```

Also, upon http://mailsender.asc/setups/add

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   /disk/www/mailsender/app/Controller/SetupsController.php on line 69

```
SetupsController.php (line 69 is the "find" on add function)
public function add() {
// The relations belongs, has many etc.
$users = $this->Setup->User->find('list');
```

(IT suggested /cake upgrade all for fix, and it seemed to fix the above but broke other things, such as logout and login).

Can Anyone help?

I was wondering also if are there any steps I should take upon moving my whole app from windows local machine to unix ubuntu.

Thank you in advance !
Best regrds.

Carlos 
from Tijuana, México.

unix version:

Linux genesi 3.0.0-12-generic-pae #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:37:17 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

php version:
Localhost: Version 5.3.0
genesi (production server) : Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6

Answer (score 0):

`users.php` should be `user.php` (singular)

Comment: user.php ok. The model es user.php. That was only a typo in my Question.  --- ! ----